# How to redirect user to action inside another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I try to write a method that when call it user redirect to action inside another controller. I use `return Redirect("~/" + redirectUrl + "/" + paymentInfo.ObjectIdDepartue);` statment for do this. and test type of this method by `RedirectResult`  , `ActionResult` but dont work.

What is problem?

```
 public RedirectResult PayViaCredit(int paymentId)
        {
            var paymentInfo = db.Payments.Find(paymentId);
            //Decrease Credit
            Profile userProfile = _utility.GetProfileOfUser();
            decimal decreasedCredit = userProfile.Credit - paymentInfo.Price              using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    db.ProcUpdateProfileCredit(decreasedCredit, userProfile.UserId);
                    //Update Payment
                    paymentInfo.Transactionsuccess = true;
                    paymentInfo.state = 3;
                    paymentInfo.Confirmed = true;
                    db.Entry(paymentInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["InvoiceNumber"] = paymentInfo.Id.ToString();
                    transactionScope.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    _errorLog.Error("CreditPayment.cs/PayViaCredit", "", e.Source, "Message:::" + e.Message + "---InnerException:::" + e.InnerException);
                    transactionScope.Dispose();
                }

            }

            string redirectUrl = _creditPayment.GetRedirectUrlCreditPayment(paymentInfo);
            return Redirect("~/" + redirectUrl + "/" + paymentInfo.ObjectIdDepartue);
        }
 public ActionResult AfterPaymentBank()
    {
   return View();
     }
```

Comment: Is `redirectUrl` contains an absolute Url? Anyway, there's no reason to use `~` for redirection.

Comment: My url is such as ~/Charter/AfterPaymentBank .I test with out ~ but do not  work

Comment: can you post the code for AfterPaymnetBank action ?

Comment: what value u get in paymentInfo.ObjectIdDepartue ?

Comment: paymentInfo.ObjectIdDepartue is int

Comment: so AfterPaymentBank takes no parameter. I guess the url formed is Charter/AfterPaymentBank/someint.

Comment: even if u are passing parameter it should be Charter/AfterPaymentBank?objectid=2

Comment: what is the value of "redirectUrl" value when you debug?

Comment: "redirectUrl" value when I debug  is "~/Charter/AfterPaymentBank"

Comment: call only this return Redirect(redirectUrl) ; remove tild symbol.

Comment: I test with out ~ but do not work

Comment: Use return RedirectToAction("AfterPaymentBank" ,"Charter");

Comment: Please also note a viewresult cannot be directly made as redirectresult.

Answer (score 0):

First of all keep your data in TempData.

```
TempData["myData"] = paymentInfo.ObjectIdDepartue;
```

Then

```
return Redirect("/ControllerName/ActionName");
```

What ever is your **redirectUrl** , give it a shape like this.

```
TempData["myData"] = paymentInfo.ObjectIdDepartue;
redirectUrl = redirectUrl.Substring(1); // or what ever you thing appropriate for your URL
return Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

Now inside "ActionName" action method , type cast your TempData to your desire type.

```
public ActionResult ActionName()
{
 var myData=(myType)TempData["MyData"];
 // and proceed....
}
```